# php login logout using SSO

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, single-sign-on, session-cookies

I have a project done with codeigniter.
I use a company public login page(SSO-OAM) to my project home page. I capture the HTTP header value in login validation function( *getallheaders()* ) .
But when I want to logout , I first need to  destroy all sessions.
since those are all Httponly type , what is the best way to logout and redirect to SSO login page? how to modified http header?

Comment: Show code of what you have done and what you dont understand ..

Comment: Hi I have update my question plz check

Comment: I don't understand why do you use anything from headers to validate login? With proper header I will be able to access your site..

Comment: most login validation are done with main login portal. So start from my page I only need some info from header I don't need to care that part now.

Comment: Ok but $this->login_model->get_user($b); looks like triggering logic depending on header param. And this is not right. You can just check (validate) param but you should not use it to trigger any logic. In your case when you redirect from logout to login you keep the same headers and they are processed at your login . If you check the session before this header it will be empty.

Comment: sorry about my poor english, now I just want to do something exactly same as (fire bugs->cookies->delete session cookies) in my logout function.

Answer (score 0):

> I use a company public login page

Do you mean an SSO provider?

If so, it should provide a URL which you either (re)direct the browser to when the user invokes logout, or which you call from PHP.

If you told us what the SSO was, or the protocol it implemented then we might be able to suggest what is going wrong. I would expect that it would need a different instruction than 'login' to end the session.

Comment: yes it's a singe sign on app which is OAM. Once the user logs in there, OAM would redirect the user to my site with some header variable I needed.